# Which option is better? adding subview into cell directly or into cell contentView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, addsubview

I have read this link [UITableViewCell Closer look](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1). I found that `UITableViewCell` content view is a subview of the cell. But in the most of case people used to add subviews in cell directly not in a `UITableViewCell` contentView. And i am also following the same.

So which is the better option to add subviews into cell? Can any one highlights which is better approach to do it properly.

Also does is properly working when we use auto layout?

Comment: @Andrew Barber: I have explain what needs to be there in question. I think you should put on hold 50% of SO question, if it is so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content view is resized automatically, for example when the "delete" or "move" indicators appear. So if you want your subview to be positioned correctly in these cases, the content view is where you want to put your subview.

When you add your subview directly to the cell, you are responsible for ensuring everything looks correct when those accessory views are visible.

Comment: Thank you i got it. So now onwards i have to add subviews in UITableViewCell content view right?

Comment: You don't _have_ to. It depends on your use-case, what you're trying to do. But very often, the content view is the right place.